# Coloured text with shadow/frame on pygtk labels

Tags: python, fonts, colors, gtk, pygtk

I have a set of strings that get displayed on same labels.  I want each string to have a different text colour based on this python hashing function:

```
def get_colour_from_string(string):
    """A (very) simple none cryptographic hash function mapping a string
    to a 'unique' RGB colour.

    :param String string: A string parameter.
    :returns: A colour hex number.
    """
    return '#{}'.format(md5(string).hexdigest()[:6])
```

Clearly, these will return more or less random RGB values which means that some of those will be illegible on the background colour.

Is there a way to create a shadow over the text of the label so that colour has a boarder? If so, jhow can I get a colour with good contrast to the text for said boarder?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the CSS `text-shadow` property on your label.